# Exclude images or other binary files from Ant filterset

Tags: ant, filter

How to exclude images and other binaries from filtersets? The filterset operation corrupts images after copy operation. I guess it might corrupt other binary files like MP3 or videos too.

This is the copy task:

```
<target name="copyCore" description="Copy core files and folders">
    <copy todir="${deploy.dir}" includeEmptyDirs="no">
        <fileset dir="${src.dir}">
            <patternset refid="core.files" />
        </fileset>
        <filterset refid="myFilterSet"></filterset>
    </copy>
</target>
```

This is the filterset:

```
<filterset id="myFilterSet">
    <filter token="author" value="${author}" />
    <filter token="title" value="${title}" />
    <filter token="module" value="${module}" />
    <filter token="lang" value="${lang}" />
    <filter token="buildDate" value="${build.date}" />
    <filter token="buildTime" value="${build.time}" />
</filterset>
```

Is there a way to exclude files based on file types in filtersets?

Answer (score 1):

In your [patternset](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/patternset.html), `exclude` the binary file types by file extension.

```
<exclude name="**/*.mp3"/>
<exclude name="**/*.mp4"/>
```

And/or, `include` only the text file types you want, by file extension.

```
<include name="**/*.txt"/>
<include name="**/*.py"/>
```

Specifically to answer your question, no there is not a way within the filterset itself to include or exclude files by type or name pattern.

[Filterset](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterset.html)s are designed to filter within text files. The Ant manual page says:

> Note: When a filterset is used in an operation, the files are
>   processed in text mode and the filters applied line by line. This
>   means that the copy operations will typically corrupt binary files.
>   When applying filters you should ensure that the set of files being
>   filtered are all text files.

You need to exclude binary files *before* they hit the filterset.

Comment: This is similar to what I've already implemented. However, my question was if we could exclude in _filtersets_. Thanks.

Comment: Updated answer. No filterset itself does not do that.